# Servlet/Tomcat file path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, localhost

After assembly by Maven, put war-file on external Tomcat server. When the servlet is started, there is a `FileNotFoundException`, it can not find `2.html` file (path is relative to - `"2.html"`). This file is in the root of the application. When I launched project  with built-in Eclipse internal server Tomacat(Ran as - run on  server) - everything worked, and the file is located (the path was an absolute - `"F: /javaEEBelhard/Task-4/WebContent/WEB-INF/1.html"`).

Here is the code in Eclipse:

```
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileIntputStream = new FileInputStream("2.html");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileIntputStream, CHARSET_NAME);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            writer.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you not missing an open parenthesis `{` after `try`?

Comment: it would not compile ..

Answer (score 0):

If deploying war - there's your problem. I bet the file doesn't exist because its in the WAR file. (And the File api looks at the file system)

If you need to read files reliably - use `servletContext.getResource(path)` or `servletContext.getResourceAsStream(path)`